# How can I prevent numbers from being affected by rtl editing?

Tags: android, xml, right-to-left

I have a multilingual application. I have an order screen. There are numerical expressions like the date on this screen. How can prevent numbers affected rtl editing in XML(textView) ?
[image]

Comment: Care to include your XML file and style.xml in the question? We can only assume what's going on underneath.

Comment: In ambiguous situations you can set the direction using a span. You use <span direction=" .... with ltr, rtl, or auto.

Comment: It's not `<span direction="ltr">` but either `<span dir="ltr">` or `<span style="direction:ltr;">`